# Avoid magic strings when working with Chakra Ui

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

A problem, I keep running into with Chakra Ui are "magic strings". Let's look at an example of muted text:

```
function Example() {
    const color = useColorModeValue("gray.400", "gray.200");
    return (
       <Text color={color} />
    )
}
```

**What's the problem with this code:** In my app, I want to share the muted color between many components. However, defining it explicitly as a string means that I have to remember that muted text has a value of "gray.400". If I have another component that wants to use muted text, I have to copy the string "gray.400" to all other components. I will end up with lots of strings that make it really hard to change things across the entire app. I explored two solutions so far:

**Solution 1 - TextStyles API**: Chakra comes with a `textStyles` API out of the box but this doesn't work well for more complicated situations (what if I want to have a `hover` and `active` state with different colors?).

**Solution 2 - Create a global object**: I've created a hook`useConsistantStyles()` that returns a theme-like object with values, e. g.: `{"borderLight": "gray.200"}`. However, this feels like I'm fighting the library.

I'd really love to have a better solution since I keep running into this.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped or there's any way I can enhance it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably late but for any new onlookers, since Styled System v1.17.0, chakra ui has semantic tokens. The [changelog](https://chakra-ui.com/changelog#25-01-2022) and [docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/features/semantic-tokens) have some details but the important bit is:

> Semantic tokens provide the ability to create css variables which can change with a CSS condition.

CSS conditions would be states like dark mode or hover etc.

In this case, you would define a semantic token like so (with a better token name):

```js
const customTheme = extendTheme({
  semanticTokens: {
    colors: {
      nicelyNamedToken: {
        default: 'gray.400',
        _dark: 'gray.200',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

import the theme however you currently do, and then anywhere the theme is present, you should be able to just use the token

```js
function Example() {
    return (
       <Text color='nicelyNamedToken' />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Solution 2 is actually *that bad* -- but I agree that it feels like everything *should* be accessible since it already exists.

If you're using a chakra **theme**, you can actually import the theme (i.e: `import { theme } from "@chakra-ui/react"`

And then you can start accessing things off of that object, like `colors` [image] (`t` is the `theme` import)

Note: you still have to 'know' the `keys` on the object, but this is at least an existing, consistent dictionary that you can reference.

*I have not tested this with different color themes, etc.*

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry for my late reply. Thanks for your answer. I still haven't found a good solution for this. IMO the `theme` is best accessed (from within components) with `useTheme` which returns the same object as a direct import (with the correct overwrites applied). My main problem is still finding a way to add consistency without the explicit strings. I'll keep exploring and post an answer to this question when I find it. If nothing better is available I'll go with solution 2.